# Перечисление.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Видимо, показалось, что мужик - сильный, умеет, может.

Видимо, показалось, что мужик сильный, умеет, может.

Натыкался на оба варианта.Какой верен? И почему?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Подлежащее "мужик", "сильный, умеет, может"- сказуемые.  По правилу тире не ставится(подлежащее - существительное,сказуемое - прилагательное). Тире возможно как интонационное, авторское.

Answer (score 2):

Более предпочтительным является вариант: Видимо, показалось, что мужик - сильный, умеет, может.

Авторское тире можно ставить/не ставить в предложении "Видимо, показалось, что мужик - сильный".

В приведенном же примере однородный ряд является как бы АВТОРСКИМ, так как включает в себя грамматически разные сказуемые, их и желательно отделить паузой и тире.